# C++ - Read a text file in as a string of words, then split the string into a vector

Tags: c++, string, class, vector

Suppose the contents of "grades.txt" are:

```
    David 99 94 95
    Mike 91 84
    John 100 85
    Lexa 76 88 90 74 85 76
    Paul 83 95
    Ryan 71 72 85
    Tommy 95 96
    Joseph 100 83 85 86
    Denise 100 90 76
    Ava 80 90
```

The first line of the file is indicated by the name of each student. The preceding lines after that are a random collection of each student's grades.

My question pertains to how could I read the file in as a string of words and split the string into a vector, so that I can organize each element into the correct location of my class Students. If there is a simpler method to accomplishing this, I would appreciate that as well. Thank you for any help provided.

Here is my class Students:

```
    class Students {
    public:
        Students();
        ~Students();

    private:
        string name;
        int grades;
    };
```

Comment: break the problem up, google cpp references for the problem. Be able to read the file into strings, use a readline function, then parse the strings to find spaces, cut the values up, store the grades in an array for each student. Develop the program incrementally from start to finish, i.e. build->test->improve. There's no reason to start with a data structure, start with opening the file, reading values, break them up, then work out how to store them. Iterative development: at each program iteration, you implement one extra stage in the processing, get that working then add the next step.

Answer (score -1):

you can try boost::split.
eg:

```
//split strFileBuffer with space and get the string vector.
string strFileBuffer;
vector<string> strs;
boost::split(strs, strFileBuffer,boost::is_any_of(" "));
```